# Searching data using different keys

Tags: c++, stl

I am no expert in C++ and STL.

I use a structure in a Map as data. Key is some class C1.
I would like to access the same data but using a different key C2 too (where C1 and C2 are two unrelated classes).

Is this possible without duplicating the data? 
I tried searching in google, but had a tough time finding an answer that I could understand.

This is for an embedded target where boost libraries are not supported.

Can somebody offer help?

Answer (score 4):

You may store **pointers** to `Data` as `std::map` values, and you can have two maps with different keys pointing to the same data.

I think a *smart pointer* like **`std::shared_ptr`** is a good option in this case of shared ownership of data:

```
#include <map>       // for std::map
#include <memory>    // for std::shared_ptr

....

std::map<C1, std::shared_ptr<Data>> map1;
std::map<C2, std::shared_ptr<Data>> map2;
```

Instances of `Data` can be allocated using `std::make_shared()`.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the Standard Library, but Boost offers `boost::multi_index`

Comment: My mistake. :( I forgot to mention that this is for an embedded target where Boost libraries are not supported. I will update the question.

Comment: `+1` This answer is still useful for people who are not constrained by it.

Answer (score 3):

### Two keys of different types

I must admit I've misread a bit, and didn't really notice you want 2 keys of different types, not values. The solution for that will base on what's below, though. Other answers have pretty much what will be needed for that, I'd just add that you could make an universal lookup function: (C++14-ish pseudocode).

```
template<class Key> 
auto lookup (Key const& key) { }
```

And specialize it for your keys (arguably easier than SFINAE)

```
template<>
auto lookup<KeyA> (KeyA const& key) { return map_of_keys_a[key]; }
```

And the same for `KeyB`.

If you wanted to encapsulate it in a class, an obvious choice would be to change `lookup` to `operator[]`.

---

### Key of the same type, but different value

#### Idea 1

The *simplest* solution I can think of in 60 seconds: (simplest meaning exactly that it should be really thought through). I'd also switch to `unordered_map` as default.

```
map<Key, Data> data;
map<Key2, Key> keys;
```

Access via `data[keys["multikey"]]`.

This will obviously waste some space (duplicating objects of `Key` type), but I am assuming they are much smaller than the `Data` type.

#### Idea 2

Another solution would be to use pointers; then the only cost of duplicate is a (smart) pointer:

```
map<Key, shared_ptr<Data>> data;
```

Object of `Data` will be alive as long as there is at least one key pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in these cases is use non-owned pointers. I store my data in a vector:

```
std::vector<Data> myData;
```

And then I map pointers to each element. Since it is possible that pointers are invalidated because of the future growth of the vector, though, I will choose to use the vector indexes in this case.

```
std::map<Key1, int> myMap1;
std::map<Key2, int> myMap2;
```

Don't expose the data containers to your clients. Encapsulate element insertion and removal in specific functions, which insert everywhere and remove everywhere.

Comment: What's a *non-native* pointer? How do you search in such `set`?

Comment: Smart pointers (I will edit my answer to make it clearer). You search using the maps.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of "searching using the maps"? I still think you're making a terrible mistake here, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Bartek `Data * pMyData = myMap1[someKey];`

Comment: And how are the maps populated, then?

Comment: @Bartek All this structure is private of my class. You encapsulate element insertion in a method which takes Data, Key1 and Key2 as parameters. Then you add Data to the std::vector, and two pairs of Key1/2 and a pointer to Data in the std::set.

Comment: @Bartek: Edit: It should actually be a vector<Data>, not a set<Data>. It is clear that Data can be repeated.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb. In this case do I have to delete from myData and two maps when I have to delete an entry?

Comment: @NeonGlow Yes. Encapsulate element deletion in one unified method, which removes everywhere.

Comment: This is of much help. Thanks.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thank you for all your clarifying comments.

Comment: `std::set` is workable, as existing elements are never moved when new elements are inserted, but `std::vector` may periodically resize itself and invalidate all the pointers to data you've got in `myMap[12]`....

Comment: @TonyD Hmm. _And_ the user must remember to take the address of the object _once in the vector_ in the first place, not the parameter's address. Maybe it would be better to just work with the index in the vector instead of pointers to Data, since access by index is O(1) and the index is of course guaranteed not to change.

Comment: @TonyD The fact you pointed out, however: pointers being invalidated, is a red sign which invalidates my original answer. I will review it more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Bartek's "Idea 1" is good (though there's no compelling reason to prefer `unordered_map` to `map`).

Alternatively, you could have a `std::map<C2, Data*>`, or `std::map<C2, std::map<C1, Data>::iterator>` to allow direct access to `Data` objects after one `C2`-keyed search, but then you'd need to be more careful not to access invalid (erased) `Data` (or more precisely, to `erase` from both containers atomically from the perspective of any other users).

It's also possible for one or both `map`s to move to `shared_ptr<Data>` - the other could use `weak_ptr<>` if that's helpful ownership-wise.  (These are in the C++11 Standard, otherwise the obvious source - boost - is apparently out for you, but maybe you've implemented your own or selected another library?  Pretty fundamental classes for modern C++).

EDIT - hash tables versus balanced binary trees

This isn't particularly relevant to the question, but has received comments/interest below and I need more space to address it properly.  Some points:

1) Bartek's casually advising to change from `map` to `unordered_map` without recommending an impact study re iterator/pointer invalidation is *dangerous*, and unwarranted given there's no reason to think it's needed (the question doesn't mention performance) and no recommendation to profile.

3) Relatively few data structures in a program are important to performance-critical behaviours, and there are plenty of times when the relative performance of one versus another is of insignificant interest.  Supporting this claim - masses of code were written with `std::map` to ensure portability before C++11, and perform just fine.

4) When performance is a serious concern, the advice should be "Care => profile", but saying that a rule of thumb is ok - in line with "Don't pessimise prematurely" (see e.g. Sutter and Alexandrescu's C++ Coding Standards) - and if asked for one here I'd happily recommend `unordered_map` by default - but that's not particularly reliable.  That's a world away from recommending every `std::map` usage I see be changed.

5) This container performance side-track has started to pull in ad-hoc snippets of useful insight, but is far from being comprehensive or balanced.  This question is not a sane venue for such a discussion.  If there's another question addressing this where it makes sense to continue this discussion and someone asks me to chip in, I'll do it sometime over the next month or two.

Comment: `unordered_map` can, and usually will have lookup in `O(1)`, compared to `O(log N)` in `map`. Do you think this is *not* a compelling reason?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: not compelling... no. Big-O notation's insightful, but for many containers you may have a sense for the number of potential elements - e.g. students per school is likely hundreds or thousands, so O(logN) is around 10 comparisons for `std::map` - that may easily outperform a `unordered_map` if hashing key fields is expensive and/or collision prone. Care=>profile. Further, there are benefits of `map`s including in-order iteration, and elements not needing to be copied/moved once inserted (i.e. pointers/references/iterators not being invalidated by further insertions).

Comment: It's obvious you can't use `unordered_map` when you need ordering. However, I think that your claim about ten comparisons being faster than hashing might not necessarily be true; hashing is usually nonbranched arithmetical operation, that would be much faster on modern CPUs.

Comment: @DeadMG: it's hard to resist layer on layer of "but consider...", but I'll restrict myself to what I've edited in to the answer for now.  Feel free to take me up on my offer to discuss elsewhere if you're keen.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider having a plain `std::list` holding all your data, and then various `std::map` objects mapping arbitrary key values to iterators pointing into the list:

```
std::list<Data> values;
std::map<C1, std::list<Data>::iterator> byC1;
std::map<C2, std::list<Data>::iterator> byC2;
```

I.e. instead of fiddling with more-or-less-raw pointers, you use plain iterators. And iterators into a `std::list` have very good invalidation guarantees.

Comment: "And iterators into a std::list have very good invalidation guarantees." - no better than `std::map`, and you've now got three containers to maintain instead of two....

Comment: @TonyD: The comment about the iterator invalidation was done with the answer by Daniel Daranas in mind (who uses integers to index a `std::vector`). That being said, it doesn't really matter whether you have three or two containers to maintain: you will have to wrap this stuff in a class to make sure that all internal contains (no matter whether it's two or three or what their types are) are always in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at first holding two map for shared pointers sound very cool. But you will still need to manage this two maps(inserting, removing etc...).

Than I came up with other way of doing this. 
My reason was; accessing a data with x-y or radius-angle. Think like each point will hold data but point could be described as cartesian x,y or radius-angle .

So I wrote a struct like

```
struct MyPoint
{
    std::pair<int, int> cartesianPoint;
    std::pair<int, int> radianPoint;

    bool operator== (const MyPoint& rhs)
    {
         if (cartesianPoint == rhs.cartesianPoint || radianPoint == rhs.radianPoint)
             return true;
         return false;
    }
}
```

After that I could used that as key,

```
std::unordered_map<MyPoint, DataType> myMultIndexMap;
```

I am not sure if your case is the same or adjustable to this scenerio but it can be a option.